# Can a .NET database integrate with wordpress?

Tags: .net, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a database of 1000+ products, descriptions, client info ect that are built on a .net software. I want to build/design a new ecommerce store in Wordpress (database: MySQL). Is there anyway to integrate the old database into a new Wordpress site?

This would save me the work of having to create 1000's of new products in wordpress...

Thanks

Comment: MySQL is not a ".NET database". I don't know what a ".NET database" is.

Comment: Also, research the export and import options on the two databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to get WordPress to use [MSSQL](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-integrate-wordpress-with-ms-sql-server-database) or Access (assuming that is what you mean by .NET) without a lot of work (it is definitely possible, but you may need to re-write the database class), but there is a way to get your data across. It's called the [MySQL migration toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/mysql-migration-toolkit-indepth-sourcedb-mssql.html). It is supposed to be very easy to use and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write your storefront in such a way that it accesses the database, as long as you aren't getting rid of the database. People have been using MySQL as the backend for websites for many years.

From the sounds of it, you may want to get a consultant on board to help with the design.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider an ETL tool for data migration like MS SSIS.